# How to pass this key word outside of onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help. I am passing `this` key word inside the onclick function. if user need to call the same function without using the onclick event how it will be called using javascript.I am explaining the scenario below.

```
<input name="optional_0_0_ans" id="optional_0_0_ans" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Answer" value="" type="text"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this,0,0,1);"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  

<script>
function createNew(evt,index,childindex,hidevalue){


}
</script>
```

On the above code i am passing the `this` keyword inside the onclick event.Here suppose user wants to call the `createNew` function some where else and wants to pass the same `this` key word then how it will be done.Please help me.

Comment: You can do createNew.call(this[, otherParameter, ...])

Comment: `this` refers to the DOM element, so they would just pass a reference to a DOM element: `createNew(someElement,0,0,1);`.

Comment: the this keyword should  give  the same properties as the onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the onclick attribute `this` refers to the current DOM Element. So if you want to achieve the same behavior, you can simply get and parse the DOM Element yourself:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#optional_0_0_ans button');
createNew(button, 0, 0, 3);
```

Comment: here this key word holds the button object noy input field.

Comment: yes, because it does so in your example too (in the example the onclick attribute is on the button). But you can easily change this by changing the selector and the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> Here suppose user wants to call the `createNew` function some where else and wants to pass the same `this` key word then how it will be done.

That's not possible since `this` only exists *inside* the event handler. The "same `this`" doesn't exist outside of the handler.
I guess what you mean is that they want to pass the same or a similar value. So what is the value of `this`? It's a DOM element. They just need to get a reference to a DOM element and pass that:

```
var someElement = // get reference to a DOM element
createNew(someElement,0,0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below code:

```
$(".btn-success").on("click", function(){
    someFunction(this, param1, param2,...)
})
```

Where ".btn-success" is a class assigned to button on which click you want to call a JavaScript function. You can also use id in selector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ,add id to your element will be more easy to handle ...

*I added id to your button element to illustrate*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="btn" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this,0,0,1);"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  

<script>
function createNew(evt,index,childindex,hidevalue){    
  alert(evt.type);  //alert button when click
}
createNew(document.getElementById('btn'),4,5,4); //alert button when run
</script>
```